# errors were found while checking the disk drive for /home

Tags: boot, home-directory, boot-repair, badblocks

I'm having a problem with booting into my Ubuntu computer. The screen stuck at boot with the message

```
errors were found while checking the disk drive for /home.
```

After that, I enter the command that corresponds to /home folder:

```
fsck /dev/sdb2
```

The console show

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1  
e2fsck 1.42.9(4-Feb-2014)  
/dev/sdb2: clean, 324327/6111232 files, 18260779/24413952 blocks
```

I've searched for answers but with no results.
So, what can I do now to fix my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It seems to be that there was a small typos in my **fstab** file.

```
UID=00e0172b-f19c-470c-bbf7-5e5b135d52e1 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

I've changed **UID** to **UUID** and my computer booted normally again. Still, thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

The message says some errors were found on the filesystem which fsck will not fix automatically,since it may affect your data so you should do it manually.

To do this, press M (when you be asked for) - this will drop you into a root console

```
fsck /dev/sdXX
```

Replace XX with your /home disk name partition

If this doesn't work try the command

```
sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdX
```

Replace X for your harddisk.

Comment: I enter
    fsck /dev/sdb2, which corresponds to my /home folder. Then the console show
    fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
    e2fsck 1.42.9(4-Feb-2014)
    /dev/sdb2: clean,  324327/6111232 files, 18260779/24413952 blocks
After that, I reboot the computer, but it still stuck at boot. What can I do now? @New-User

Comment: then show what!?!

Comment: tried with sdb, sdb1, sdb2, sdb3 but with no results :(

Comment: Maybe try to run `badblocks` on your sdb drive.  The command from terminal window would be `sudo badbocks -sv /dev/sdb` to run a check on the entire drive.

Comment: I entered that command and this message appeared:

    sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdb
    Checking blocks 0 to 125034839
    Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errdone                                                 
    Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight It seems that your disk is good with no defects... Try to boot with a liveCD session and chroot and check the `dmesg`

Comment: how can I do that, I'm not good at Linux commands

Comment: Oops, I just realized my misspelling, it is supposed to be `sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdb`

Comment: yes it should be

Comment: Are all these commands being run from the Recovery Menu going to the root shell prompt?  When you drop to the root shell prompt, you normally cannot make changes to your drive by running `fsck /dev/sdXX` with the partition mounted.  Unmount the partition first by typing in `umount /dev/sdb2` since that is your home mount, then proceed by running `fsck /dev/sdb2`.  Technically no partitions should be mounted when checking the file systems.  Just a thought.